# Output number of person types per department using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, aggregate-functions

I need the count of doctors, residents, nurses, and patients per department.  However, it yields no results.  If I remove 3 types, it gives me a list of counts of remaining person type. How to make the results appear when having all person types included?

Thanks.

```
`SELECT DISTINCT
    department.departmentID,
    COUNT(doctor.doctorID) AS number_of_doctors,
    COUNT(resident.residentID) AS number_of_residents,
    COUNT(nurse.nurseID) AS number_of_nurses,
    COUNT(patient.patientID) AS patient_count

FROM department
    INNER JOIN person ON department.departmentID = person.departmentID
    INNER JOIN doctor ON doctor.employeeID = person.personID
    INNER JOIN resident ON resident.employeeID = person.personID
    INNER JOIN nurse ON nurse.employeeID = person.personID
    INNER JOIN patient ON patient.patientID = person.personID
GROUP BY department.departmentID'
```

Comment: Since you're using an inner join of both nurse, doctor, resident, and patient, you are essentially querying for persons that are all four. You're better off doing a subselect for each category.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you can't have a person that is simultaneously doctor, resident, nurse and patient. So use `left join`s :

```
SELECT
    de.departmentID,
    COUNT(do.doctorID  ) AS number_of_doctors,
    COUNT(re.residentID) AS number_of_residents,
    COUNT(nu.nurseID   ) AS number_of_nurses,
    COUNT(pa.patientID ) AS patient_count
FROM department de
INNER JOIN person   pe ON de.departmentID = pe.departmentID
LEFT  JOIN doctor   do ON do.employeeID   = pe.personID
LEFT  JOIN resident re ON re.employeeID   = pe.personID
LEFT  JOIN nurse    nu ON nu.employeeID   = pe.personID
LEFT  JOIN patient  pa ON pa.patientID    = pe.personID
GROUP BY de.departmentID
```